# How do I install additional XAMPP default applications after XAMPP is already installed

Tags: php, apache, xampp, sendmail, mercury-mta

Whilst recently installing XAMPP I only installed some of the default applications (specifically: Apache, MySQL, PHP and phpMyAdmin). I now need to make use of more default applications and would like to install Mercury and Fake Sendmail.

My question is: Can I install these other applications without having to uninstall and then install XAMPP all over again? If yes, how?

I tried launching the original XAMPP .exe and selecting only the applications I want, but it seems like it will overwrite all current files with a clean install (not what I want).

XAMPP / PHP version 5.6.3
 | My OS: Windows 7

Comment: run the xampp install again and try not to install xampp but the add ons. make a backup of the /htdocs and backup your php.ini file before doing that. also do a mysqldump of your database.